# Unable to logout user using session_destroy in PHP?

Tags: php, session

Here is my code included at the top of each page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// More Code Here //
```

Here is my code for login button :

```
function Login() {
// Connecting to Database  
  if($rows == 1) {
  // Setting a Cookie
  $_SESSION['login'] = true;
  }
mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Here is my code for logout button:

```
function Logout() {
  session_destroy(); 
  return true;
}
```

I call these functions under conditions like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'logout') {
  $bool = Logout();
  if($bool == true) {echo 'Logged Out!'; }
}
```

but it never echos `Logged Out`. What am I doing wrong here? This is also the sequence of code in my PHP file. First login function, then logout function and then condition to check which function to call.

This is the HTML form:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['login']==true) { ?>
  <li>
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
      <button type="submit" value="logout">Log Out</button>
    </form>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
  <li>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="login">Login</button>
    </form>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can we see the html form?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to give your button a `name` attribute to correspond with the `$_POST` array:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="logout" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="margin-left:10px">Log Out</button>
```

Comment: I still have to click twice on the logout button to log out.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar Twice? As in double-click or send two requests?

Comment: I click once it echos logout. After that I still see the logout button. If I refresh the page or click the logout button again then it changes to login.

Comment: Try adding `session_start();` after `session_destroy();` in your `Logout()` function.

Comment: I think I have logged out but the way I am using PHP code to show logout button makes it necessary to refresh. I will try this and also update my code in question. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Adding `session_start()` after `session_destroy()` did not work.

Comment: There might be other code interfering. I tried all the code you shared, and it worked for me on my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87598/discussion-between-sujata-hulsurkar-and-stuart-wagner).